# IIS 7 Host Headers Not Working

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, localhost, hostheaders

I'm having a problem binding my websites on my local windows 7 machine.  When I create a new website I specify the local machine path, then I edit the bindings to add a host header of site1.com.  When I enter "http://site1.com" in the browser address bar, it responds with:

```
The connection has timed out
The server at site1.com is taking too long to respond.
```

I theorize that it has something to do with my DNS trying to retrieve the ip address for site1.com on the net as opposed to my local implementation.  If I leave the host header blank, bind to port 8080, and enter "http://localhost:8080" in the address bar it works fine though.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure you modify `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` to include your site1.com domain.

```
   127.0.0.1     site1.com
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks a ton, it was very frustrating.  Do you know if there is a way to automate the process so I don't have to manually edit the hosts file each time.  Otherwise, I could just leave the host header blank, edit the hosts file, and map to a different port with a friendly name just as easily.

Comment: Glad I could help!  I don't know of a way to automate it.  I always have to edit hosts when developing off of local repos.